# Update Panel updates

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a ASP.NET AJAX Autocomplete Textbox and Two other dropdownlist in a Update Panel.
On selection of an item in Autocomplete Textbox, I want to populate Dropdown list from Database.

any idea how to achive this?

Thanx
Vks

Answer (score 0):

For this particular application, I suggest that you use a [ASP.NET AJAX ComboBox](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx) instead of the Autocomplete Textbox.
With the ComboBox, it will be easier to trigger an async postback for your updatepanel and then bind the Dropdown list to the Database.